# Update values in a column with another only if they are blank, empty or NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

So I wrote this snippet of code to search the entire Warehouse Column of data frame 1 for occurrences of cell values that appear 20 times or more and if the cell value satisfies this requirement, the code will write the cell value of the Warehouse column over the cell value of the GeneralDescription column. It is working but I want to add to it so it will not overwrite a cell value unless it is empty or NaN or ''.

```
import pandas as pd 

df1.Warehouse=df1.Warehouse.str.upper()
```

and for some odd reason i cant indent the next line of code four spaces

```
df1.loc[df1.groupby('Warehouse').Warehouse.transform('count').gt(20),'GeneralDescription']=df1.Warehouse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Augment your masking condition, AND it with another that indicates whether a column contains one of those empty values.

```
i = df1.groupby('Warehouse').Warehouse.transform('count').gt(20)
j = df1.Warehouse.isin([np.nan, 'Empty', ''])

df1.loc[i & j, 'GeneralDescription'] = df1.Warehouse
```

---

Alternatively, when loading in your data, specify `na_values` so everything becomes NaN:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., na_values=['Empty', '', 'NaN', 'nan'])
```

And you can then just do:

```
i = df1.groupby('Warehouse').Warehouse.transform('count').gt(20)
j = df1.Warehouse.isnull()
df1.loc[i & j, 'GeneralDescription'] = df1.Warehouse
```

Which is arguably faster.